# Is it possible to remove login password and sudo password on 20.04 LTS permanently?

Tags: login, sudo, password

The situation arise when I want to exchange my used laptop which requires password authentication during login and while issuing sudo commands. The other party wants no password at all. Is that even possible?

Comment: No, it isn't and it shouldn't be. Not even Windows allows that.

Comment: When you say "remove login password" do you mean the ability to log in to ubuntu without the need to enter your password? That part is possible but removing the need for sudo protection is ill-advised but possible see [this reference](https://www.maketecheasier.com/use-sudo-without-password-linux/)

Comment: Ok thanks. I have already tried using sudo visudo .. that seems to work bypassing the requirement at commandline. But I would like to know how to log in to ubuntu without the need to enter the password. (I tried enabling auto login at user settings after which it seems it logins but it still asks for after a while!)

Comment: This is the Gnome keyring which by default uses your user password and unlocks automatically at login. If you have passwordless login, it does not unlock and asks you when some app tries to unlock it (e.g. Chromium or `sshagent`). You can remove the password from the keyring by using an empty password.

Answer (score 1):

To remove login and sudo passwords do the following:

1. **Login password**:

> - Enable **`Automatic Login`**. (This should allow you to log in automatically into the OS) .
> - Also, remove the password from the keyring by **`using an empty string`**.
>   An alternative (*but I won't advise since I don't know the implications*) may be to remove the file `login.keyring` as shown below:
>
>   ```
>   $ rm ~/.local/share/keyrings/login.keyring
>   ```

2. **Sudo password**:

> - Edit the sudoers file:
>
>   ```
>   $ sudo visudo
>   ```
> - Disable the `sudo` password:
>
>   - First, check whether there’s an existing rule with your alias.
>      (In the file `sudoers`. I think it is found in `/etc/`).
>      If there is, it should look like: `YOUR_USERNAME ALL=(ALL) <SOMETHING>:ALL`.
>
>     ```
>      ~$ sudo nano /etc/sudoers
>     ```
>   - If there isn’t, move to the end of the file and create a new rule there as follows:
>
>     ```
>      YOUR_USERNAME ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
>     ```
>   - Save the changes and exit the editor: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>.
> - Voilà! You can now test it by installing an app.

Hope this goes a long way to help you...